# Type should be one of javascript array - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a case:

```
const types = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const fn = (arg: *in types*) => {};
```

Is there a way to tell Typescript that `arg` can have type of any element in `types` array?

**Note**: I dont want to hardcode it, e.g. `arg: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'`

Comment: Why not use `any` as the type?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava why use `any` when there is a concrete type the variable could be?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You have to adjust the type inference of the array with `as const` (that changes the type from `string[]` to `("a" | "b" | "c")[]`), then you can lookup `(typeof types)[number]`.

```
 const types = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
 const fn = (arg: (typeof types)[number]) => {};
```